# How to authenticate one microservice into another(spring cloud)

Tags: java, architecture, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-cloud

I am learning microservice architecture and currently I have following architecture:

[image]

User can access as `hello-service`  as `hello-world-service`. It is clear for me how to implement **user** authorization using oauth2. For achieve it I use oauth2 (spring-security-oauth2). But it is not clear for me how to authorize `hello-world-service` to `hello-service`.

Can you explain me this stuff?

**P.S.** you can find full source code here: https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-cloud

**P.S.2**

I watched several presentations and found out following slide(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg6A-4wUulA):

[image]

### P.S.3

My implementation attempt which doesn't work https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-cloud

Comment: Are you looking for a way to mix requests from `hello-world-service` to `hello-service` coming either from an actual user (and propagating oauth2 principal) or a pure service-to-service call?  Or do you always want to authorize the calls as being the `hello-world-sevice`?